# im having problems with gmod ACE arrays

Tags: arrays, garrys-mod

ive been stuped by how to use a radar in gmod ACE and want to kno how ( i have no expirience with e2 and need alot of help)

if you have expirience please send in here e2 code that could take  position from array thank you.